# Finding constants to make f(g(x)) and g(f(x)) equal.

Tags: functions, polynomials

Let $f(x) = ax + b$ and $g(x) = cx^2$, where $a$, $b$, and $c$ are constants.
Compute $f\circ g$ and $g\circ f$. Determine for which constants $a$, $b$, and $c$ it
is true that $f\circ g =g\circ f$.

So I end up with $f(g(x)) = a \times cx^2 + b$ and  $g(f(x)) = c(ax+b)^2$.
And so: $a cx^2 + b = c(ax+b)^2$.

I end up expanding to: 
$acx^2 +b=a^2cx^2 + 2abcx + b^2c$. Not sure what to do after this.

Comment: Move all terms to the same side and combine like terms. Since the other side is zero, and the equation must hold for all values of $x$, this means that all coefficients must be zero. So you have three equations in three unknowns. (Also, note that $acxx$ is $acx^2$.)

Answer (score 1):

Two polynomials are the same if and only if their coefficients are the same. In this case,
$$f(g(x)) = acx^2 + b, \qquad g(f(x)) = a^2 c x^2 + 2abc x + b^2 c,$$
so equating coefficients gives
\begin{align}
ac &= a^2 \\
2abc &= 0 \\
b &= b^2 c .
\end{align}
We can rewrite the first equation as
$$a(c - a) = 0,$$
which suggests we split into two cases.

Comment: Check the first equation again

Comment: Thanks, Hagen, I've fixed the missing parenthesis.